# R update a tibble using data from a second tibble as row and column

Tags: r, tibble

I have an empty tibble full of NA's with the rows and columns, respectively named for id numbers and all the dates in a period of time.  For example, this code:

```
tbl <- tibble(PERSONAL_ID = c("A", "B", "C", "D"))
dates = as.character((seq(as.Date("2016-01-01"), as.Date("2016-01-05"), by="days")))
tbl[dates] <- NA
tbl <- column_to_rownames(tbl, var = "PERSONAL_ID")
```

I have a second tibble that contains columns matching up one ID number with one date, as in this example:

```
enrollments <- tibble(ID = c("D", "B", "C", "D"),
                      date = c("2016-01-01", "2016-01-03", "2016-01-05", "2016-01-02"))
```

What I would like to do is add "1" to the row and column of the first tibble (tbl) corresponding to the ID and date listed in the second tibble (enrollments).  For the example code above, the desired output would be:

```
  2016-01-01 2016-01-02 2016-01-03 2016-01-04 2016-01-05
A       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>        <NA>      <NA>
B       <NA>       <NA>          1        <NA>      <NA>
C       <NA>       <NA>       <NA>        <NA>         1
D          1          1       <NA>        <NA>      <NA>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a base R approach. For enrollments, I combine the `date` and `ID` into one string for each row. Then, for `tbl`, I create a table that is filled with the date and rowname. Then, I use `match` to match the values from `enrollment` with those in `tbl`. I use `arrayInd` to get the column and row index. Finally, I `replace` the `NA` values in `tbl` with `1` for the extracted column-row indices.

```
replace(tbl, arrayInd(match(do.call(
  paste, subset(enrollments, select = c("date", "ID"))),
t(outer(colnames(tbl), rownames(tbl), FUN = paste)
)), .dim = dim(tbl)), 1)
```

Here is a slightly different `tidyverse` approach by using `rows_update`. Here, I pivot `enrollments` to a wide format, then bind to `tbl` (but with no rows) in order to have the same columns. Then, I update the rows in `tbl` with the new format from `enrollments`.

```
library(tidyverse)

rows_update(tbl %>% rownames_to_column("ID"), enrollments %>% 
              mutate(value = 1) %>% 
              pivot_wider(names_from = "date", values_from = "value") %>% 
              bind_rows(tbl[0,])) %>% 
  column_to_rownames("ID")
```

**Output**

```
  2016-01-01 2016-01-02 2016-01-03 2016-01-04 2016-01-05
A         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
B         NA         NA          1         NA         NA
C         NA         NA         NA         NA          1
D          1          1         NA         NA         NA
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a `tidyverse` approach.

1. First change your `tbl` from a `wide` format to a `long` format so that it matches the format of `enrollments`.
2. Create a `Count` column in `enrollments`, and every row would be `Count = 1`.
3. Then `left_join` the transformed `tbl` with `enrollments` using `ID` and `date` as the joining field.
4. Finally, transform the `long` format back to a `wide` format and set `rownames`.

```
library(tidyverse)

left_join(tbl %>% rownames_to_column(var = "ID") %>% 
            pivot_longer(-ID, names_to = "date", values_to = "Count") %>% 
            select(-Count), 
          enrollments %>% mutate(Count = 1), 
          by = c("ID", "date")) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = "date", values_from = "Count") %>%
  column_to_rownames(var = "ID")
```

### Output

```
 2016-01-01 2016-01-02 2016-01-03 2016-01-04 2016-01-05
A         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
B         NA         NA          1         NA         NA
C         NA         NA         NA         NA          1
D          1          1         NA         NA         NA
```

### Your dataset as reference

```
tbl
  2016-01-01 2016-01-02 2016-01-03 2016-01-04 2016-01-05
A         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
B         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
C         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
D         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
```

```
enrollments
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  ID    date      
  <chr> <chr>     
1 D     2016-01-01
2 B     2016-01-03
3 C     2016-01-05
4 D     2016-01-02
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a data.table approach, using `PERSONAL_IDS`, `dates`, and `enrollments`

```
dcast(rbind(
  rbindlist(lapply(setdiff(PERSONAL_ID,enrollments$ID), \(x) data.table(ID=x, date=dates)))[,value:=NA],
  enrollments[,value:=1]
  ), ID~date,value.var="value")
```

Output:

```
   ID 2016-01-01 2016-01-02 2016-01-03 2016-01-04 2016-01-05
1:  A         NA         NA         NA         NA         NA
2:  B         NA         NA          1         NA         NA
3:  C         NA         NA         NA         NA          1
4:  D          1          1         NA         NA         NA
```